# Code-First Entity Framework Multiple Collections with Many to Many

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have another Entity Framework question here. I have a complicated object called Book and that object has a number of collections of type Contributor such as Writer, Letterer, Colorist, etc. Contributors are not necessarily scoped to a particular role though. So the same contributor (with the same ContributorId) could be both a Writer and a Colorist, for example.

```
public Book {
        public ICollection<Contributor> Writers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> Artists { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> Pencilers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> Inkers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> Colorists { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> Letterers { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> CoverArtists { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Contributor> OtherContributors { get; set; }
}

public Contributor {
     public int ContributorId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am having trouble, viewing the examples I have found here and on other sites, determining how I would signify the appropriate model. I would expect a Db Model something like this. What I want to avoid is a model wherein I have a separate table for every Contributor Role, or a separate row in the Contributor table for every instance in which a contributor is associated with a book in any role.

```
+ Books 
     --BookId
+ Contributors
      --ContributorId
+ BookContributors
      --BookId
      --ContributorId
      --Discriminator
```

I am such as ADO.NET guy that I am not really finding this too enjoyable, but I am determined to become at least borderline proficient in this important framework.

**A Quick Note:**
Since opening this question, I got pulled away at work and haven't had the time to thoroughly review the answers and play around with the results. But I didn't want to leave the bounty hanging as I appreciate the answers everyone has provided. So I selected the answer that appeared of the most interest to me starting out. I want to thank everyone though for this.

Comment: You can't have both the class model and the data model, at least not as a direct mapping, so which of the two are you willing to sacrifice?

Comment: To be honest, neither. I have already done this project with ADO. But the point of this question on StackOverflow, and this exercise as a whole, for me, is to learn something new. I *should* know the EF by now and do not. So I am open to whatever you want to suggest and think best.

Comment: @Goblyn27 I am not quite clear on what your question is. Are you looking for how to implement the model you have proposed using Entity Framework Code First?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked on a solution that implements the model you proposed although it works a bit different than what you would expect. Hope this answers your question.

**Models**

```
[Table("Book")]
public class Book
{
    [Column("BookId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Writers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Artists { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Pencilers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Inkers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Colorists { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> Letterers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> CoverArtists { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Contributor> OtherContributors { get; set; }
}

[Table("Contributor")]
public class Contributor
{
    [Column("ContributorId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
}

// Contributor Type is one of the following options: Writer, Artist, Penciler, etc.
[Table("ContributorType")]
public class ContributorType
{
    [Column("ContributorTypeId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContributorTypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("BookContributor")]
public class BookContributor
{
    [Column("BookContributorId")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BookContributorId { get; set; }

    [Column("BookId")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Column("ContributorId")]
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }

    [Column("RoleId")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContributorId")]
    public virtual Contributor Contributor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual ContributorType Role { get; set; }
}
```

**Database Context**

AppDbContext.cs:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new AppDbInitializer());
    }

    public AppDbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AppDbContext>(new AppDbInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Contributor> Contributors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ContributorType> ContributorTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BookContributor> BookContributors { get; set; }
}
```

AppDbInitializer.cs:

```
public class AppDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(AppDbContext context)
    {
        // default contributor types
        var contributorTypes = new List<ContributorType>();
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Writer" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Artist" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Penciler" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Inker" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Colorist" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "Letterer" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "CoverArtist" });
        contributorTypes.Add(new ContributorType() { Name = "OtherContributor" });

        // adding it to the context
        foreach (var type in contributorTypes)
            context.ContributorTypes.Add(type);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

**Wrapping everything together**

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // enter name of the connection string in App.Config file
        var connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."];
        using (var dbContext = new AppDbContext(connectionSettings.ConnectionString)) 
        {
            // Creating a book
            var book = new Book();
            dbContext.Books.Add(book);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Creating contributor
            var contributor = new Contributor();
            dbContext.Contributors.Add(contributor);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // Adding contributor to the book
            var bookContributor = new BookContributor()
            {
                BookId = book.BookId,
                ContributorId = contributor.ContributorId,
                RoleId = dbContext.ContributorTypes.First(t => t.Name == "Writer").ContributorTypeId
            };
            dbContext.BookContributors.Add(bookContributor);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            // retrieving a book
            var book = dbContext.Books.Where(b => b.BookId == 2).FirstOrDefault();
            if (book != null) 
            {
                book.Writers = 
                    from contributor in dbContext.Contributors
                    join bookContributor in dbContext.BookContributors on contributor.BookId equals bookContributor.BookId
                    join contributorType in dbContext.ContributorTypes on contributorType.ContributorTypeId equals bookContributor.ContributorTypeId
                    where 
                        bookContributor.BookId == 2 and
                        contributorType.Name == "Writer"
                    select contributor;

                // do the same for other types of contributors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow,  a lot to take in. I will have to read it again after my coffee. Thanks!

Comment: @Goblyn27 I waited with commenting until you made up your mind which answer to accept, but one thing I particularly don't like about this approach is that you have to do the heavy lifting of filling a book's collections yourself, and if you want to get a list of books from the database, this will cause the infamous n + 1 query pattern (you might even say m*n + 1). And you won't be able to easily combine books and contributors in queries. Just an example, how are you going to query books having only writers? You'll always have to write manual joins. No navigation properties involved.

Comment: @GertArnold I cant answer the question because I don't know. I am too new to the Entity Framework method of doing this. In your example question, it would be pretty simple for me to query books having only writers in SQL, and generally speaking that is how my brain functions after 15  years of development. I recognize that EF is very different, but I am not knowledgeable enough to even see where those differences apply in most cases.

Comment: I wrote the code this way due to the requirements of the problem however as @GertArnold has pointed out, it is definitely not efficient at all. In my experience with Entity Framework, sometimes I have had to create dedicated stored procedures to perform operations when the underlying Entity Framework is just not efficient enough.

Answer (score 3):

Create similar collections in the Contributor entity with M:N mapping and use the InverseProperty attribute to declare which collection in Contributor class corresponds with which collection in the Book class.

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Writers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Artists { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Pencilers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Inkers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Colorists { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> Letterers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> CoverArtists { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contributor> OtherContributors { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        Writers = new List<Contributor>();
        Artists = new List<Contributor>();
        Pencilers = new List<Contributor>();
        Inkers = new List<Contributor>();
        Colorists = new List<Contributor>();
        Letterers = new List<Contributor>();
        CoverArtists = new List<Contributor>();
        OtherContributors = new List<Contributor>();
    }
}

public class Contributor
{
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Writers")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> WriterOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Artists")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> ArtistOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Pencilers")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> PencilerOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Inkers")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> InkerOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Colorists")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> ColoristOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Letterers")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> LettererOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("CoverArtists")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> CoverArtistOfBooks { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("OtherContributors")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> OtherContributorOfBooks { get; set; }

    public Contributor()
    {
        WriterOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        ArtistOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        PencilerOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        InkerOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        ColoristOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        LettererOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        CoverArtistOfBooks = new List<Book>();
        OtherContributorOfBooks = new List<Book>();
    }
}
```

The usage is then quite simple:

```
using (var dc = new MyDbContext())
{
    // create sample data
    var book1 = new Book() { Name = "Book 1" };
    dc.Books.Add(book1);

    var contrib1 = new Contributor() { Name = "Contributor 1" };
    var contrib2 = new Contributor() { Name = "Contributor 2" };
    var contrib3 = new Contributor() { Name = "Contributor 3" };
    dc.Contributors.Add(contrib1);
    dc.Contributors.Add(contrib2);
    dc.Contributors.Add(contrib3);

    dc.SaveChanges();



    // add relationships
    book1.Writers.Add(contrib1);
    book1.Artists.Add(contrib1);
    book1.Artists.Add(contrib2);
    book1.OtherContributors.Add(contrib3);
    dc.SaveChanges();
}

// verify that the contributor 1 has both Artist and Writer relations
using (var dc = new MyDbContext())
{
    var contrib1 = dc.Contributors.Single(c => c.Name == "Contributor 1");
    var hasWriter = contrib1.WriterOfBooks.Count == 1;
    var hasArtist = contrib1.ArtistOfBooks.Count == 1;
    if (!hasWriter || !hasArtist)
    {
        throw new Exception("Houston, we have a problem.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will review it in a little bit once I am more awake.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on books at test.polarcomputer.com 
If you have a book object and this object has writer,publisher,designer ..whoever, 
you need just 3 object : 
1.book object
2.contributor object.
3.integration object

book object has 
- bookid
- bookname

contributor object has 
 - contributorid
 - name
 - typeofcontributor // 0-writer 1-colorist 2-CoverArtists 3-whoever

integration object has 
 - bookid
 - contributorid
 - typeofcontributor // 0-writer 1-colorist 2-CoverArtists 3-whoever

Check this if i understant it truly , i can give you full solution.

Comment: Yes, that is the basic idea.

Answer (score 2):

The data model you show is OK, but one thing is clear. You can't map this as a pure many-to-many association. That's only possible if the junction table `BookContributors` only contains `BookId` and `ContributorId`.

So you always need an explicit `BookContributor` class, and getting a collection of one of the contributor types is always going to take this basic shape:

```
book.BookContributors
    .Where(bc => bc.Type == type)
    .Select(bc => bc.Contributor)
```

Clunky, compared to what you have in mind. But no way to get around it, I'm afraid. What's left is a few options in the implementation details.

#### Option 1: Get all contributors, filter later.

First, let's get the basic model right:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookContributor> BookContributors { get; set; }
}

public class Contributor
{
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookContributor> BookContributors { get; set; }
}

public class BookContributor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contributor Contributor { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasMany(b => b.BookContributors)
        .WithRequired(bc => bc.Book)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contributor>().HasMany(c => c.BookContributors)
        .WithRequired(bc => bc.Contributor)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ContributorId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookContributor>()
                .HasKey(bc => new {bc.BookId, bc.ContributorId, bc.Type});
}
```

(by the way, here I avoid the term 'Discriminator' because that suggests TPH inheritance, which isn't applicable - yet).

Now you could add properties to `Book` like these:

```
[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<Contributor> Writers
{ 
    get 
    {
        return BookContributors.Where(bc => bc.Type == "writer")
                               .Select(bc => bc.Contributor);
    }
}
```

The downside of this approach is that you always have to ensure that books are loaded with their `BookContributors` and *their* `Contributor`s included, or that lazy loading is possible. And you can't use these properties directly in a LINQ query. Also, it's somewhat hard to get books and only their unique contributors (i.e. distinct).

#### Option 2: Inheritance - essentially the same

You could make `BookContributor` an abstract base class having a number of inheritors:

```
public abstract class BookContributor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contributor Contributor { get; set; }
}

public class Artist : BookContributor
{ }

public class Writer : BookContributor
{ }
```

`BookContributor` now needs a surrogate key, `Id`, because EF will now use a field `Discriminator`, which is hidden, so it can't be configured as part of the primary key.

Now `Book` could have properties like...

```
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Artist> Artists
    {
        get { return BookContributors.OfType<Artist>().ToList(); }
    }
```

...but these will still have the same downsides as mentioned above. The only possible advantage is that you can use types now (with compile-time checking) in stead of strings (or enum values) to get to the various `BookContributor` types.

#### option 3: A different model

Maybe the most promising approach is a slightly different model: books and contributors, where each association between them can have a collection of contributor types. `BookContributor` now looks like this:

```
public class BookContributor
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Contributor Contributor { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<BookContributorType> BookContributorTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And a new type:

```
public class BookContributorType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int ContributorId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Modified mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookContributor>().HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.ContributorId });
```

Additional mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BookContributor>().HasMany(bc => bc.BookContributorTypes).WithRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<BookContributorType>().HasKey(bct => bct.ID);
```

With this model you can either just get books and their distinct contributors, if you're not interested in the contributor's types...

```
context.Books.Include(b => b.BookContributors
                            .Select(bc => bc.Contributor))
```

...or with the types...

```
context.Books.Include(b => b.BookContributors
                            .Select(bc => bc.Contributor))
             .Include(b => b.BookContributors
                            .Select(bc => bc.BookContributorTypes));
```

...or books with only writers...

```
context.Books.Select(b => new
                     {
                         Book = b,
                         Writers = b.BookContributors
                                    .Where(bc => bc.BookContributorTypes
                                                   .Any(bct => bct.Type == "artist"))
                     })
```

Again, the latter query can be wrapped in a property...

```
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Artist> Artists
    {
        get
        {
            return BookContributors
                     .Where(bc => bc.BookContributorTypes
                                .Any(bct => bct.Type == "artist"))
                     .Select(bc => bc.Contributor).ToList();
        }
    }
```

...however, with all aforementioned cautions.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. I will review it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like that :

```
    [Table("tblBooks")]
    public class BookTbl
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("tblContributor")]
    public class ContributorTbl
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ContID { get; set; }
        public string Contributor { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("tblIntegration")]
    public class IntegrationTbl
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int IntID { get; set; }
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BookID")]
        public BookTbl Book { get; set; }
        public int ContID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ContID")]
        public IntegrationTbl Integration { get; set; } 
    }
```